# Property [file] does not exist on this collection instance Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have three tables('users,cars and photos').

**users table**

[image]

**photos table**

[image]

I want to display the newest image file for user avatar picture. In this case I want to show as profile avatar photo with id = 2 because it's the latest photo for the user(id=1) because of imageable_id=1 and because imageable_type is for User(for user avatar). App\Models\Car belongs to cars and I don't need that for now.

**Summary: Want to display the newest photo for the user avatar.**

I Am using this code below inside my blade file:

```
<img src="{{$detected_user->photo->file}}" alt="">
```

In Controller I use $detected_user to authenticate user which is logged in and I use '->photo'(relationship inside my model). '->file' is the name of the column inside my 'photos' table.

**User Model**

```
public function photo() {
    return $this->morphMany('App\Models\Photo', 'imageable');
}
```

**Cars Model**

```
public function photo() {
    return $this->morphMany('App\Models\Photo', 'imageable');
}
```

**Photo Model**

```
public function imageable() {
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

Comment: Seems like `$detected_user->photo` a collection of photos, not just a single photo. If you show us how you write the relationship in your User-model, it will be easier for us to see how they are fetched. It seems to be a one to many relationship though.

Comment: MorphToMany Relationship. I edited the post so see..

Comment: Yes. When I type in tinker $user->photo I get all photos which are related for that $user. When I type $user-photo->file I get error for collection instance for ['file']. I solved in some how but now it's just displaying the first photo which was uploaded.. I want to show the latest one.

Comment: That's because a collection is just that, a collection of objects. It's the objects that has the `file` property, not the collection. You need to reference the specific photo you want to use. Either loop through them using something like `foreach($user->photo as $photo) { echo $photo->file; }` or access a specific one directly: `$user->photo[0]->file`

Comment: Tried that. Getting error: Attempt to read property "file" on bool

Comment: I'm starting to think that this is hasOneThrough relationship because like this I am getting collection of photos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the `User` model you can define two relationships

```php
//App\Models\User.php

public function photos()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Models\Photo', 'imageable');
}

public function latest_photo()
{
    return $this->morphOne('App\Models\Photo', 'imageable')->latest('id');
}
```

In the view

```html
<img src="{{$detected_user->latest_photo->file}}" alt="">
```

And similarly for the `Car` model

```php
//App\Models\Car.php

public function photos()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Models\Photo', 'imageable');
}

public function latest_photo()
{
    return $this->morphOne('App\Models\Photo', 'imageable')->latest('id');
}
```

Comment: Yes of course. Thanks again!